# finding lenth of consecutive characters given an index

Tags: python, regex

I am a regex noob, Let us say I have a string:

```
String = 'ABBBABBAAAAAABAAABAAAAAABAAABAABAAAAABAAAAABAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABABABAAA'
```

I want to find the length of the chain of consecutive A's or B's only from a given index as the start of the chain.

I used `re.findall('A+',String)` but it does not accept the start index as an argument.
Is there a method that can do this directly?

Comment: [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.findall) does support a start and end position, but only if you create a [`RegexObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject) object first.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you guys, I want it to return the lentgth of the chain beginning only at a given index

Comment: How do you expect `A+` to match `B`s? Your question is very confusing.

Comment: I love such questions.  _I want to ask something but I'm unsure what to ask.  Ok, I'll ask something and keep changing it on the fly._

Comment: @devnull I think I posted the question clearly, please just reread it

Comment: @microarm15 If one needs to _reread_ it, then it's obvious how clear it would be.

Comment: I would suggest you guys change your uppish attitude and listen to noob questions with more attention.

Comment: @microarm15 Oi, we are all volunteers here. _Nobody_ here has to help you at all. If you want help, treat others with some respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I've managed to figure what you're trying to achieve.

The following might do what you're looking for:

```
s = 'ABBBABBAAAAAABAAABAAAAAABAAABAABAAAAABAAAAABAABBBBBBBAAAAAAABABABAAA'
for i in range(len(s)):
  res = re.match(r'^(.)\1*', s[i:]).group(0)
  print i, res, len(res)
```

(I've looped over the entire string as an example.  You could instead pass a specific index.)

This would produce both the length of consecutive characters at different indices in the string.  Upon execution it'd produce:

```
0 A 1
1 BBB 3
2 BB 2
3 B 1
4 A 1
5 BB 2
6 B 1
7 AAAAAA 6
8 AAAAA 5
9 AAAA 4
10 AAA 3
11 AA 2
12 A 1
13 B 1
14 AAA 3
15 AA 2
16 A 1
17 B 1
18 AAAAAA 6
19 AAAAA 5
20 AAAA 4
21 AAA 3
22 AA 2
23 A 1
24 B 1
25 AAA 3
26 AA 2
27 A 1
28 B 1
29 AA 2
30 A 1
31 B 1
32 AAAAA 5
33 AAAA 4
34 AAA 3
35 AA 2
36 A 1
37 B 1
38 AAAAA 5
39 AAAA 4
40 AAA 3
41 AA 2
42 A 1
43 B 1
44 AA 2
45 A 1
46 BBBBBBB 7
47 BBBBBB 6
48 BBBBB 5
49 BBBB 4
50 BBB 3
51 BB 2
52 B 1
53 AAAAAAA 7
54 AAAAAA 6
55 AAAAA 5
56 AAAA 4
57 AAA 3
58 AA 2
59 A 1
60 B 1
61 A 1
62 B 1
63 A 1
64 B 1
65 AAA 3
66 AA 2
67 A 1
```

Comment: it does more than I wanted actually, thanks and sorry if the question was not clear enough.

Comment: @microarm15 Giving examples of input and expected output in the question help.  It saves everyone from frustration and helps one get better answers.

Comment: Okay, frankly I thought it was a simple/common problem, but I guess now I couldnt explain  what I wanted clearly, sorry again.

Comment: @microarm15 You can explain more clearly by giving example input and output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `index` contains your desired starting position, and you only want a single match, and only if that match starts at exactly that position, you can use

```
re.match('A+', String[index:])
```

If you have to do it inside the regex, you can use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but that's going to be much slower:

```
re.search('(?s)(?<=^.{{{}}})A+'.format(index), String)
```

(which gives you `re.search('^(?s)(?<=.{100})A+', String)` if `index` is `100`).

Comment: But I think this can return any chain after that index, I want it to return the chain beginning only at this index. Thank you for helping me anyways :)

Comment: @microarm15: Why are you using `re.findall()` then? And if there is a `B` at that index, you don't want any match at all?

Comment: it may start with A or B, I want the length of this very chain beginning only at this specific index, ONLY.